# R networkD3 skip nodes for radialNetwork()

Tags: r, networkd3

I'm trying to make a radial network following this code I found online:

> fileName <- system.file("extdata", "useR15.csv", package="data.tree")
>   useRdf <- read.csv(fileName, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
>
> useRdf$pathString <- paste("useR", useRdf$session, useRdf$room,
>   useRdf$speaker, sep="|")
>
> useRtree <- as.Node(useRdf, pathDelimiter = "|")
>
> useRtreeList <- ToListExplicit(useRtree, unname = TRUE) 
>   radialNetwork( useRtreeList)

When I try building the tree with my data, I get this error, because I have NA (Null) values for some sequences:

> Error in if (length(nms) != n || any(nms == "")) stop("'options' must
>   be a fully named list, or have no names (NULL)") :    missing value
>   where TRUE/FALSE needed

I would like to turn these NA values into skipped nodes (essentially varying connection lengths), rather than deleting the row or incorporating 'NA' into my network. The sequences of variables as they would occur in a radial network I would expect to see are below:

> Full sequence: Column1 --> Column2 --> Column3 --> Column4
>
> Incomplete sequence 1: Column1 --> NA --> Column3 --> NA

What I want to see:
Column1 --> --> --> Column3 (end of branch)

> Incomplete sequence 2: Column1 --> Column2 --> NA --> Column4

What I want to see:
Column1 --> Column2 --> --> --> Column4 (end of branch)

Is there a function I can include to the code above that can execute this?
Or is there a better graph that would easily allow for varied connection lengths in a radial network?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn’t you convert the NA nodes to an empty string or a space or other non-printing character?

Comment: Thanks! What actually worked was leaving cells blank, and made the network perfectly :)